# Highstock chart - issue with xaxis label

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have some data with last date of each month.

for e.g.

```
[1504137600000, 52.2]
[1501459200000, 52.1]
[1498780800000, 52.4]
[1496188800000, 53.1]
[1493510400000, 52.7]
[1490918400000, 52.4]
[1488240000000, 53.3]
```

When i plot the chart using this data.
xAxis label not showing properly.

[image]

its showing xAxis Label, `Feb '08` as starting label,
I want to start with `Jan '08` from first label.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xtgj4y0d/1/

Answer (score 2):

To specify labels for exact timestamps, you can use `tickPositions` array. You also need to use `Highcharts.dateFormat` function to format dates.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.dateFormat

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wL7o3zd3/

Comment: thanks for the answer... but i have one more issue.. its working fine for less data, but for large data it did not auto adjusting the labels. which was working previously. http://jsfiddle.net/wL7o3zd3/1/

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha  you can change `"selected" : -1,` to `"selected" : 1,`  check http://jsfiddle.net/8rknf75r/

Comment: but it doesn't work when we zoom out in navigator...working fine if i remove `tickPositions`... http://jsfiddle.net/8rknf75r/2/ .. it auto adjusting the xAxis label while zoom-in or zoom-out in navigator.. can we achieve this using `tickPositions`...?